# Trying to read this file in parts. read some part and skip some

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file, I want to read some part of the file and skip some part untill I get to the end of the file. This is what I have but I am not getting my desired result. The idea is to read through all the lines and check if it starts with either "CH" or "CL" if not move to the next line until the end of file and store all those that match the criteria

```
 new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("c:\\demo5.properties\\"));
    while(( br.readLine()) != null ){
        if (br.readLine().startsWith("CH") ||  br.readLine().startsWith("CL")) {
        buf = new StringBuffer();
        buf.append( br.readLine());

        while (br.readLine()!= null && !br.readLine().startsWith("#") &&  !br.readLine().contains("claimID")){
            buf.append( br.readLine()).append( "\n" );
        }
         z = buf.toString();

         System.out.println(z);

        s3+= z;
    }
        br.readLine();
```

**FILE FORMAT**

```
 CH.field 
 CH.field
 CH.field
 CH.field
 CH.field
 #CH.field
 #CH.field
 #CH.field
 #CH.field
 *********
 **
 *********
 CL1.field
 CL1.field
 CL1.field
 CL1.field
 CL1.field
 *****************
#Result.CL1.field
#Result.CL1.field
#Result.CL1.field
Result.CL1.field
*********
CL4.field
CL4.field
CL4.field
#CL4.field
#CL4.field
#CL4.field
***********

   #Result.CL4
  #Result.CL4
  #Result.CL4
  #Result.CL
 Result.CL4
  CL5.field
 CL5.field
 CL5.field
 #CL5.field
 #CL5.field
```

OUTPUT

```
CH.fieldCH.field

CL1.field#Result.CL1.field
CL4.field
CL4.field
```

#CL4.field

```
CL5.fieldCL5.field
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this loop:

```
while (br.readLine()!= null 
       && !br.readLine().startsWith("#")
       &&  !br.readLine().contains("CH.field.claimID")){
    buf.append( br.readLine()).append( "\n" );
}
```

You're calling `readLine()` *4 times*. That's going to read four different lines. You want something like:

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null &&
       !line.startsWith('#') &&
       !line.contains("CH.field.claimID")) {
    buf.append(line).append("\n");
}
```

At least, I think that's what you want - I'm finding the description a little confusing. Anyway, that will read each line, stop when it reaches either the end of a file *or* a line starting with "#" *or* a line containing "CH.field.claimID"... but build up a `StringBuffer` containing all the lines before that point.

Answer (score 0):

A call to readLine() will read one line that ends with a '\n' and then file pointer will point to next line (or it'll point to whatever after '\n' to be more precise).

for e.g.

Before readLine():

filePointer --> This is first line \n

-----------------  This is second line \n

After readLine():

------------------This is first line \n

filePointer --> This is second line \n

You are calling readLine() multiple times thinking that it refers to same line. Which is where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I gathered that you want to store all lines that begin with "CH" or "CL" and ignore the rest.

All the br.readline calls are moving that file reader pointer to the next line.

The formatting looks odd to me, maybe try this:

```
    String input = "";
    buf = new StringBuffer();
    new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("c:\\demo\\TestIL_Cross_000005.properties\\"));

    // read in the line to "input" if it exists
    while((input = br.readLine()) != null ){
        // check for starting string match
        if (input.startsWith("CH") ||  input.startsWith("CL")) { 
            // append to whatever data struct here since it matches       
            buf.append(input + "\n");
           // print "input" here for testing
        }
    }
```

Comment: I still want to check if the line contains certain string after verifying if it starts with CH or CL, and if it does skip that line and move to the next

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Well I'm glad Jon was able to solve this for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic mistake that you have made in your code. You must store the data returned by readLine() method in a String variable, and use it for further operations. You are calling the readLine() method every time, you want to perform operation on the received String, as a result it every time fetches new data and previous data is lost.

Modified version of your code :

```
         new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("c:\\demo\\TestIL_Cross_000005.properties\\"));
     String line = null;

        while(( line= br.readLine()) != null ){
            if (line.startsWith("CH") ||  v.startsWith("CL")) {
            buf = new StringBuffer();
            buf.append(line);

            while (line!= null && !line.startsWith("#") &&  !line.contains("CH.field.claimID")){
                buf.append( line).append( "\n" );
            }
             z = buf.toString();

             System.out.println(z);

            s3+= z;
        }

}
```

Here I have just collected the data from readLine() method in a String reference, and used in for performing different checks.